# Using Animate.css and Waypoints together – Safari works, Chrome & FF do not

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

I have a site framework that utilizes `@keyframe` options from [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), and I am using `$(window).onScroll()` (with a timeout throttle) to add a class to elements as they come into the viewport.

There are many tutorials online for this combination, but since authors on my site can choose the animation that they want in the CMS, I needed to keep the animation class inline and then trigger the animation once the element is in view.

So an example element might look like this:

```
<div class="animated fadeInUp animated__initial"> ... </div>
```

And then with `$(window).onScroll()`, I am using this this (without the throttling in place just to make the code easier to read):

```
var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
var animated = $('.animated.animated__initial');
animated.each(function() {
  var top = $(this).offset().top;
  var window_h = $(window).height();
  var top_offset = top - (window_h * .75);

  if (cur_pos >= top_offset) {
    $(this).addClass('animated__active');
  }
});
```

All that is to say that it works great in Safari (11). The animations work as expected once the element comes into view. And yet, for Firefox (58) and Chrome (65), they just "snap" into place, going from invisible to visible with no animation transition.

These are my SASS rules:

```
html.js {

  .animated {
    will-change: transform;
  }

  .animated.animated__initial {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .animated.animated__active {
    animation-duration: 750ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Even though I should not need them, both `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes are present (I am using Autoprefixer) on the animation names and keyframes.

I'm stumped as to why Safari works well but Chrome/FF does not. Its usually the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has encountered this, the fix was simple but not something I came across easily. It was trial and error.

Basically, Chrome and Firefox were animating the elements as the page loaded, as if the `animated__initial` vs. `animated__active` classes were doing nothing. Turns out, its because I should also have utilized the `animation-play-state` property.

I also played with the `visibility` property. I think Safari must set `animation-play-state` to a default of `paused` on hidden objects, while the others do not.

This updated SASS now does the trick in all three browsers, and IE 11 too.

```
html.js {

  .animated {
    will-change: transform;
  }

  .animated.animated__initial {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .animated.animated__active {
    animation-duration: 750ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
}
```